# DispatchGroup with async task

Tags: swift, concurrency, dispatch

`enter code here`I try lot of thing with the dispatch group but I can't obtain stable result. 
I use Alamofire for get data since my server. I've write a function in the Helper Class and I use this function in AppDelegate.swift.

I don't know if I put the dispatch group when I call the function so in AppDelegate or I put the dispatch group only in the function in Helper Class.

```
    func alomofireGet(URL: String, onCompletion:@escaping ((JSON) -> Void)) {
   // let group = DispatchGroup()
    var contentJSON = JSON()
   // group.enter()
    Alamofire.request(URL, method: .get).responseJSON() { (reponse) in
        if reponse.result.isSuccess {
            contentJSON = JSON(reponse.result.value!)
        } else {
            contentJSON = JSON(reponse.result.error!)
        }
     //   group.leave()
    }
  //  group.notify(queue: .main) {
        onCompletion(contentJSON)
}
```

In App delegate, I write a function who call the function in my class.

```
    func connect() {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    let _: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.removeObject(forKey: "token")
    var token = String()
    group.enter()
    Helper().alomofireGet(URL: "http://192.168.1.19/app_dev.php/login/app") { contenuJSON in
        token = contenuJSON["csrfToken"].stringValue
        group.leave()
    }
    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        let _: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.set(token, forKey: "token")
        let t: String? = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "token")
        print(t!)
   }
}
```

The problem is the variable "t" is empty. 
And when I call the keychainWrapper in app delegate, the keychain is empty also.

PS : I have other task, I've just reduce my code

Comment: So, what exactly was your problem again?

Comment: DispatchGroup is pointless for a **single** asynchronous task. Put the code in the *notify* body into the `Helper` completion block.

Comment: I have updated my response thanks

Comment: I have other task, I've just reduce my code

Comment: The reduction falsifies the question.

Comment: as much for me.

Comment: In the function " func alomofireGet" I call this function for call few request.

Answer (score 0):

```
func alomofireGet(URL: String, onCompletion:@escaping ((JSON) -> Void)) {
   // let group = DispatchGroup()
    var contentJSON = JSON()
   // group.enter()
    Alamofire.request(URL, method: .get).responseJSON() { (reponse) in
        if reponse.result.isSuccess {
            contentJSON = JSON(reponse.result.value!)
        } else {
            contentJSON = JSON(reponse.result.error!)
        }
     //   group.leave()
    }
  //  group.notify(queue: .main) {// where you call wait()function. This blocks the current thread until the group’s tasks have completed.
        onCompletion(contentJSON)
}
```

Comment: I don't call Wait function. Maybe the problem ?

Comment: I use group.notify

Answer (score 0):

I try this but is not the solution. I've remove the function in my Helper. I'have juste this function in the app delegate.

```
func connect(onCompletion : @escaping (String) -> ()) {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    var token = String()
    let _: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.removeObject(forKey: "token")
    group.enter()
    Alamofire.request("http://192.168.1.19/app_dev.php/login/app", method: .get).responseJSON() { (reponse) in
        if reponse.result.isSuccess {
            let contentJSON = JSON(reponse.result.value!)
            token = contentJSON["csrfToken"].stringValue
        } else {
            token = "Invalid Token"
        }
       group.leave()
    }
    group.notify(queue : DispatchQueue.global()) {
        onCompletion(token)
    }
}
```

when I print token, I have a empty message.

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1.5)
    connect() { token in
        print(token)
    }
    return true
}
```